# Ways to speed up scss during watch compiling in Webpack

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

TLDR; Scroll to the bottom for the answer or combine both Webpack and Dart Sass VM.  https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/releases/

Not sure if anyone else has run into this issue, but my first save while the files are being watched can take up 6-7 seconds ( 6720 ms ).

It then dips between 2-3.5 seconds typically.

I'm using Webpack 5, latest version of `sass-loader` and `sass`.  I also included `Fibers` per Webpacks recommendation and I'm really not seeing any improvement.

My JS compiles in less than a second.

I've also tried both `memory` and `filesystem` setting in Webpack cache as well. I also tried `cache-loader`.

My current SCSS rules look like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const Fiber = require('fibers');
const Sass = require('sass');
const config = require('../app.config');

module.exports = {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: config.paths.sass,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: { sourceMap: true },
            },
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: {
                    postcssOptions: {
                        config: path.resolve(__dirname, '../postcss.config.js'),
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
                options: {
                    sourceMap: true,
                    sassOptions: {
                        fiber: Fiber
                    },
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
};
```

My browser support for postcss is:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        'postcss-preset-env': {
            stage: 0,
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'not dead', '> 0.2%']
        },
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not work with Webpack itself but I know the effect from others ... there are three things to think about:

1. Sass becomes slowly as many SASS files are included to the process. Big SASS-Frameworks tend to use a lot of files and latest when you use a lot of big modules it heavily could slow down at all. Sometimes there are more modules included than needed.
2. Often the standard project settings try to to a lot of work at the same time. I.e. writing `min-files` in same process simply doubles the time. If it is that: just prepare 'min-files' at the end of your work. Up to that using additonal post-processors to autoprefix like linters and maby postcss needs extra time ...  which counts doubles when writing min-files at once...
3. JS-Sass-Compilers are slower at all. So you can save time using native SASS direct. This may not be handsome but in big projects that helped me a lot. If you may try that here the link to information how to install: https://sass-lang.com/install

Just ideas for thinking forward...

Comment: thanks for the input!

I turned off source maps and remove nested imported.  My slow times are now around 3 seconds while "cached" or back to back saves are roughly 1.8 seconds. 

I noticed I could go native sass, the problem is getting that to work along side Webpack.

Comment: I should have marked this as correct.   In the end, use a combination of both.  The Dart Sass VM and Webpack for JS / linting / browsersync ect. Webpack still watching the scss files ( browsersync injection ), but never touches it other than that. 

Using the SASS compiler natively is so freaking fast, I'm only mad at myself for not combining the 2 process sooner.

Answer (score 0):

I have a real small prototype project with a maybe two page long styles.sass and my dev build with eval etc. took 16s. That was way too high.

I tried the [cache-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cache-loader) solution and it only supports webpack 4.0 and I use webpack 5.0.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: dev@0.3
npm ERR! Found: webpack@5.76.2
npm ERR! node_modules/webpack
npm ERR!   dev webpack@"^5.75.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer webpack@"^4.0.0" from cache-loader@4.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/cache-loader
npm ERR!   dev cache-loader@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
```

Then I found a [fast-sass-loader](https://github.com/yibn2008/fast-sass-loader) node module which is also not maintained anymore.

Like in life the simplest solution are always the best. Don't use SASS as at all. I replaced my sass file with a scss file. With a relative small effort my build went from 16s to 7s and I haven't even optimized anything in the packaging yet.

I'm quite sure your reload time goes down dramatically as well, the moment you replace every sass file with a scss one.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use `sass-embedded` as implementation for sass-loader. You must install sass-embedded package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-embedded) and use it in your configuration:

```
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
      implementation: require('sass-embedded'),
      sassOptions: {
        quietDeps: true
      }
    }
}
```

For me reduced the time from 20s to 3s in dev mode and from 140s to 50s in the deployment.

I found the answer in this post: [Can I use sass-embedded as part of my sass-loader for my webpack.config.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72493778/can-i-use-sass-embedded-as-part-of-my-sass-loader-for-my-webpack-config-js)