# Can I use sass-embedded as part of my sass-loader for my webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, node-sass, dart-sass

I am trying to do something like this but for my webpack.config.js but I run into an error that states: **Unknown Sass implementation "sass-embedded"**.

I have sass-embedded installed as a module. Any sort of insight would be appreciated as to why this doesn't work or if this is even possible given that sass-embedded is in beta.

webpack.config.js:

```
{
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap : true,
        implementation: require('sass-embedded'),
        sassOptions: {
          fiber: false,
          includePaths: [
            project.paths.client('styles'),
            project.paths.base('node_modules')
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
{
   loader: 'sass-loader',
   options: {
     sourceMap : true,
     implementation: require('sass-embedded'),
   }
}
```

That improved my pipeline speed from 3min30s to 40s.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information in the [official announcement](https://sass-lang.com/blog/embedded-sass-is-live) of the first stable release of Embedded Dart Sass, I'd suggest trying the [`sass` package](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass) instead.