# How compile SCSS faster

Tags: sass, compilation

Simple topic simple question: are there a way to compile faster SCSS when you have a MASSIVE folder of partial files like this

[image]

I know more partial file you have more slow the compile is but i'd like to know if there is a way to compile faster.

Answer (score 1):

In general, sass needs a compiler written based on different programming languages to be compiled, if the speed of any of these compilers is slow for you, you can use [Sass direct](https://sass-lang.com/install) or use https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass or use compilers in faster programming languages such as java

this is good answer [(--link--)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404966/ways-to-speed-up-scss-during-watch-compiling-in-webpack)

there are three things to think about:

1. Sass becomes slowly as many SASS files are included to the process. Big SASS-Frameworks tend to use a lot of files and latest when you use a lot of big modules it heavily could slow down at all. Sometimes there are more modules included than needed.
2. Often the standard project settings try to to a lot of work at the same time. I.e. writing min-files in same process simply doubles the time. If it is that: just prepare 'min-files' at the end of your work. Up to that using additonal post-processors to autoprefix like linters and maby postcss needs extra time ... which counts doubles when writing min-files at once...
3. JS-Sass-Compilers are slower at all. So you can save time using native SASS direct. This may not be handsome but in big projects that helped me a lot. If you may try that here the link to information how to install: https://sass-lang.com/install