# Angular 10 -> Angular 16, Using Shared CSS Library, Build/Serve time is over 40 minutes

Tags: angular, sass, migration, shared-libraries

I have a production-scale Angular solution that I've just upgraded from Angular 10 -> Angular 16.

Most of that went pretty well.

We have a shared styling solution and a shared component solution so that we can leverage these common components across products.

Our shared styling solution was a set of .scss files that were compiled together using a pretty obtuse gulp file, and honestly we had been looking to get rid of this for ages. I moved the set of .scss files from our shared styles solution into our shared-components solution because there was really no good reason to have two shared libraries that were being used in all of the exact same places. I removed all of the gulp madness, referenced all of our .scss files in one master styles.scss file, and then my newly upgraded app just referenced that one styles.scss file.

That went pretty well also.

But here's the rub... I noticed that, because of the way our files reference one another and the way imports work, we were getting several stylings applied multiple times, which was just ugly to look at and difficult to modify in chrome's dev tools.

I did what's recommended in 2023 to combat this problem, which was switched our @imports to @use and @forward to cut down the redundant imports.

The minute I did this, our build times ballooned. We're talking 40+ minutes for a single build or serve.

We've tried removing all optimization from our builds, which didn't help at all. We've tried switching to another sass build library like fast-sass-loader and ran into issues with that not properly using node_modules, I've tried increasing the ram budgets... frankly I've tried a lot.

At this point, I'm losing entire days trying to figure out a problem I'm not well enough equipped to understand. I'm hoping this is a case of my `angular.json` file having something outdated in it or something, I don't really know.

If anyone knows anything I can try, I'm all ears. I'm willing to post .json files or whatever, so people can see them, but I don't even really know what would be relevant at this point.

Thank you!

Here's the `angular.json` file for the main project:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "scrubbed-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "highcharts",
              "lodash",
              "file-saver",
              "jquery"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/scrubbed-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/env.js",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/@scrubbedcompany/shared-components/assets/img",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["./node_modules"]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/moment/moment.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "src/assets/3rdParty/scrubbedcompanypendo.js",
              "src/assets/3rdParty/anychart-bundle.min.js"
            ],
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "maximumError": "7mb",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "type": "initial"
                },
                {
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "statsJson": false,
              "progress": true,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "buildOptimizer": false
            },
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "maximumError": "7mb",
                  "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                  "type": "initial"
                },
                {
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle"
                }
              ],
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "vendorChunk": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "scrubbed-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "scrubbed-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "scrubbed-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
                "inject": true
              }
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"],
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
          },
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
              "styles": [
                {
                  "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
                  "inject": true
                }
              ],
              "scripts": [],
              "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
            },
            "dev": {
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
              "styles": [
                {
                  "input": "node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css",
                  "inject": true
                }
              ],
              "scripts": [],
              "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "scrubbed-app-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "scrubbed-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "scrubbed-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

And here's the angular.json for our shared library

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "cli": {
        "analytics": false
    },
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "components": {
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "tsConfig": "projects/components/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
                        }
                    },
                    "options": {
                        "project": "projects/components/ng-package.json",
                        "tsConfig": "projects/components/tsconfig.lib.json"
                    },
                    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                        "includePaths": ["./node_modules"]
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {}
                    },
                    "options": {
                        "karmaConfig": "projects/components/karma.conf.js",
                        "main": "projects/components/src/test.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "projects/components/tsconfig.spec.json"
                    }
                }
            },
            "prefix": "scrubbed-company",
            "projectType": "library",
            "root": "projects/components",
            "sourceRoot": "projects/components/src"
        },
        "scrubbed-shared": {
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "maximumError": "5mb",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "type": "initial"
                                },
                                {
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle"
                                }
                            ],
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "vendorChunk": false
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "",
                    "options": {
                        "buildOptimizer": false,
                        "extractLicenses": false,
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "namedChunks": true,
                        "optimization": false,
                        "outputPath": "dist/scrubbed-shared",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "scripts": [],
                        "sourceMap": true,
                        "tsConfig": "./tsconfig.base.json",
                        "vendorChunk": true
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "scrubbed-shared:build"
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "scrubbed-shared:build:production"
                        }
                    },
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "scrubbed-shared:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "codeCoverage": true,
                        "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "scripts": [],
                        "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
                        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
                    }
                }
            },
            "prefix": "app",
            "projectType": "application",
            "root": "",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:class": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "skipTests": true,
                    "style": "scss"
                },
                "@schematics/angular:directive": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:guard": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:module": {},
                "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
                    "skipTests": true
                },
                "@schematics/angular:service": {
                    "skipTests": true
                }
            },
            "sourceRoot": "src"
        },
        "scrubbed-shared-e2e": {
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "scrubbed-shared:serve:production"
                        }
                    },
                    "options": {
                        "devServerTarget": "scrubbed-shared:serve",
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js"
                    }
                }
            },
            "prefix": "",
            "projectType": "application",
            "root": "e2e/"
        }
    },
    "version": 1
}
```

**Editing to add:** What I've done just now is generate an entirely new fresh Angular 16 project, and then made the following changes:

1. Gave it a package.lock reference to our shared library
2. Installed a few dependencies
3. Imported the shared library's main scss file into the new app's styles.scss file

The build time on this new app has just gone from instant to *insanely high*. So I guess I'm a little confused on what's going wrong here.

The shared library has a `styles.scss` file which `@forward`s several other `.scss` files, which either `@forward` their own files or `@use` files that were already `@forward`ed earlier in the chain to create their own css stylings, mixins, etc.

Then my main app has a `@use '@scrubbed-company-name/shared-library-name/assets/styles/styles.scss' as styles;` in it.

Am I doing this wrong? Should I be compiling the shared library's scss down into just a plain css file instead? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: yes, please add your angular.json file

Comment: @Storytellerr updated to include both relevant angular.json files

Comment: `stylePreprocessorOptions": {"includePaths": ["./node_modules"] }` looks fishy. You points to a folder that has thousands if not millions of files in it. Is there any reason you did that?

Comment: @skouch2022 We're importing some stylesheets from modules - bootstrap, etc. If we don't include that, all of the imports within the bootstrap library itself fail. We had this thought too and tried removing this line, and it made no discernible difference.

Comment: I see. It is hard to know what went wrong. I would revert back the changes for the `@forward`/`@user`. Then slowly at them back and watch for the build time. You might want to look into what they suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66404966/ways-to-speed-up-scss-during-watch-compiling-in-webpack

Comment: @skouch2022 It's really interesting, and by interesting I mean annoying. I removed all of the `@use` and `@forward` and reverted them back to `@import`. I started using `@use` only for the internal stylings and `@forward`ed them from a central file, and allowed the app to continue `@import`ing that file. Build time inflated. I tried using `@import` for the internal styling and just `@use`ing just that one global file. Build time inflated. Seems like using `@use` in any capacity inflates the build, but if I don't, styles get imported like 20 times.

Comment: If using `@use` really is the root cause, then maybe you can look into a post build clean up where the tool can remove unused or duplicate styles. There might be something like that out there.